# How to use zf2 ACL and auth storage in simplest form

Tags: zend-framework2, acl

Hi I need to use ACL in a situation where user can only login through third party service like facebook google etc and their are only two roles guest and user. Right now I am using \Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session() to store user object in session after authentication, but I don't want to apply checks on my every action to know the status of user. I want to keep it simple by using a simple access control list. I have checked many modules like zfcUser etc but they are far more complex than what I actually need. I tried to build my own ACL plugin but the documentation is not good enough and the tutorials on zf2 ACL are focusing on different cases.

Thanks in Advance for your help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155085/zend-framework-2-acl-implementation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this module can help:
[BjyAuthorize](https://github.com/bjyoungblood/BjyAuthorize)

This module is designed provide a facade for Zend\Permissions\Acl that will ease its usage with modules and applications. By default, it provides simple setup via config files or by using Zend\Db or Doctrine ORM. This module also comes with out-of-the-box support for and integration with ZfcUser.